# cocos2d CCDrawNode scale bounding box

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, bounding-box, ccaction, ccnode

I'm using cocos2d and I create a `CCDrawNode`.
The moment I call `addChild:` to add the `CCDrawNode` I call the following method to make the node scale forever:

```
CCActionScaleBy *scaleAction = [CCActionScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.3f scale:1.1f];
CCActionRepeatForever *repeatForever = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:scaleAction];
[self runAction:repeatForever];
```

Unfortunately when trying to access the `CCDrawNode` `boundingBox` it's width and height don't change with scale action.

What causes that and how can I get it's real width and height?

Thanks!

Comment: you can get the real width, height by multiplying the original width /height with the current scale value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look into the implementation of CCActionScaleBy shows that it plays around with the `scale` property of the node while not tampering the `contentSizeInPoints` property. The `boundingBox` is the rect obtained using 0,0 as origin and `contentSizeInPoints` property for width and height dimensions. 
An easy way to obtain the actual width and height would be to multiply `contentSize/boundingBox.size` with the current scale value:

```
    CGFloat actualWidth = self.boundingBox.size.width * self.scale;
    CGFloat actualHeight = self.boundingBox.size.height * self.scale;
```

Comment: Hiya,this may well answer the question... but don't forget there are total n00bs that will come to the question and wonder how this solves the problem... it's always a good idea to add some content that explains why your solution worked. :)